# How to use valdr AngularJs service Without Form Tag

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-directive, valdr

Is it possible to validate form elements without using Form tag using Valdr AngularJs Service .
If any other Plugin Avaliable to Validate form Elements please let me know.

Comment: Did you try? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ngForm` directive instead of a form tag.

```
<div ng-form="myForm" valdr-type="Person">
  <input name="lastName" ng-model="person.lastName">
</div>
```

Example: [valdr without form tag](http://plnkr.co/edit/CDnpopQ2Yx3XSP0m3er4?p=preview)